# Stone-Weierstrass analogue for $L^p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory

Let $A$ be a complex algebra of bounded measurable functions on the measure space $(X,\mu)$ (case of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure is enough for me) closed under conjugation. Assume that $A$ separates points, i.e. there is no non-trivial measurable partition of $X$ such that each function in $A$ is constant on (almost every) part. Is it true that $A$ is dense in $L^p(X,\mu)$ for $1\leq p < \infty$?

Comment: $L^1$ is a Banach algebra. The spectral calculus is probably a mess, but does this not help. Similar $L^\infty$. Then you can interpolate? 

Comment: Here is another idea: $L^p$ and $L^q$ are dual for appropiate $p$ and $q$, it is certainly enough to show that for every functional is distinguiehed by elements of $A$. This does not help for $L^\infty$, where the dual is $ba \neq L^p$.

Comment: I meant in my last sentence, then one can do $L^\infty$ seperately, if it works for $ba$. I actually would believe that $L^\infty$ implies the other stuff, since it will imply it for $L^1$, since dense in $ba$, and for all other $L^p$ since the characteristic functions are in all $L^p$ and span, and interpolation takes care over convergence in the right notion.

Comment: L^1 is not a Banach algebra for pointwise product.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: I am well aware of that fact, I consider the interval as a circle, so I have $L^1$ of group, sorry that I was not clear about that.

Comment: @MrcPlm: since the question concerns *pointwise* product, and L^1 of the circle is only an algebra under *convolution*, I don't see how your 1st comment is supposed to work. Are you suggesting interpolating between the convolution structure on L^1 and the pointwise product on L^\infty? If so, good luck with that.

Comment: One ought to be able to use the multiplicative system theorem to prove this, since that is what I view as the measure-theoretic version of Stone-Weierstrass.  The only hard part seems to be showing that these hypotheses imply $\sigma(A)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (mod null sets).  That is clearly a necessary condition for the theorem to hold, so given that we have another proof, it must be true, and there should be an easy way to show it...

Comment: Actually, proving that $1$ is in the closure of $A$ is another tricky part, unless that was supposed to be inherent in the definition of "algebra".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes (I assume that the measure is finite). Here is a proof that uses the von Neumann bicommutant theorem (or rather [Kaplansky's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky_density_theorem)).

See $A \subset L^\infty(X,\mu) \subset B(L^2(X,\mu))$ where $L^\infty$ acts on $L^2$ by pointwise multiplication. Then the assumption that $A$ separates points is exactly that the commutant of $A$ is $L^\infty(X,\mu)$, so that the bicommutant of $A$ is $L^\infty(X,\mu)$. Therefore, by Kaplansky's density theorem, any $f \in L^\infty$ with $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$ belongs to the strong operator topology closure of $\{g \in A, \|g\|_\infty\leq 1\}$. Equivalently, there is a net $g_\alpha \in A$ with $\|g_\alpha\|_\infty \leq 1$ such that, for every $\xi \in L^2$, $\|g_\alpha \xi - f \xi\|_2\to 1$. In particular (using that the constant function $1$ belongs to $L^2$), $\|g_\alpha - f\|_2 \to 0$. But by this implies that for every $1\leq p < \infty$, $\|g_\alpha - f\|_p \to 0$~: if $p<2$ this is because the $L^p \subset L^2$ (the measure is finite), whereas if $p>2$ this is the inequality $\| \cdot \|_p \leq \|\cdot \|_\infty^\theta \|\cdot \|_2^{1-\theta}$ for $\theta=1-2/p>0$.

This proves that the $\| \cdot \|_p$-closure of $A$ contains $L^\infty$, and hence it is $L^p$.

Comment: Why go to the non commutative setting, Mikael? Just use the Stone Weierstrass theorem in $K(K)$ with $K$ the Stone space of $L_\infty(\mu)$. $\mu$ induces a measure $\nu$ on $K$ s.t. for all $p$, $L_p(\mu)$ is naturally identified with $L_p(K,\nu)$.

Comment: @Bill: I am so illiterate, sorry, what is a "Stone space" here?

Comment: Presumably, the maximal ideal space or, equivalently, the Stone space of the Boolean algebra $\wp(X)$ modulo $\mu$-null sets. 

Comment: Then how do we conclude that Stone Weierstrass condition holds from the separation property? 

Comment: Bill, the Stone-Weïerstrass Theorem does not apply here because the condition of separability does not include all points in K. In addition, the density Theorem proposed by Mikael is valid for the weak*-topology of L^\infty, not for the norm topology.